# find_xml_all return {xml_nodeset (0)}

Tags: r, kml, xml2

I have recently downloaded the KML file from this [map](http://www.mountaineering-lohas.org/wp-content/plugins/leaflet-maps-marker-pro/leaflet-fullscreen.php?layer=1), and tried to use the package `xml2` to extract the information of the campsites e.g. the geolocation, the facilities around the sites etc; but I got `{xml_nodeset (0)}` at the end.

Belows are the codes I have used,

```
library(xml2)
campsites <- read_xml("file_path")
xml_find_all(campsites, ".//Placemark")
```

Here is the structure of the KML file (you may also try `xml_structure(campsites)`),

```
> library(magrittr)
> campsites
{xml_document}
<kml>
[1] <Document>\n<description><![CDATA[powered by <a href="http://www.wordpress.org">WordPress</a> &amp; <a href="https://www.mapsmarker.com">MapsMarker.com</a>]] ...
>
> campsites %>% xml_children %>% xml_children %>% xml_children
{xml_nodeset (55)}
 [1] <IconStyle>\n  <Icon>\n    <href>http://www.mountaineering-lohas.org/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/tents.png</href>\n  </Icon>\n</IconStyle>
 [2] <IconStyle>\n  <Icon>\n    <href>http://www.mountaineering-lohas.org/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/tents-1.png</href>\n  </Icon>\n</IconStyle>
 [3] <IconStyle>\n  <Icon>\n    <href>http://www.mountaineering-lohas.org/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/tents1.png</href>\n  </Icon>\n</IconStyle>
 [4] <name>é¦™æ¸¯ç‡Ÿåœ° Hong Kong Camp Site</name>
 [5] <Placemark id="marker-1">\n<styleUrl>#tents</styleUrl>\n<name>æµæ°´éŸ¿ç‡Ÿåœ° (Â Lau Shui Heung Camp Site )</name>\n<TimeStamp><when>2013-02-21T04:02:29+08: ...
 [6] <Placemark id="marker-2">\n<styleUrl>#tents</styleUrl>\n<name>é¶´è—ªç‡Ÿåœ°(Hok Tau Camp Site)</name>\n<TimeStamp><when>2013-02-21T04:02:18+08:00</when></Tim ...
 [7] <Placemark id="marker-3">\n<styleUrl>#tents</styleUrl>\n<name>æ¶ŒèƒŒç‡Ÿåœ°(Chung Pui Camp Site)</name>\n<TimeStamp><when>2013-02-22T11:02:02+08:00</when></T ...
 [8] <Placemark id="marker-4">\n<styleUrl>#tents</styleUrl>\n<name>æ±å¹³æ´²ç‡Ÿåœ° (Tung Ping Chau Campsite)</name>\n<TimeStamp><when>2013-02-22T11:02:39+08:00</ ...
 [9] <Placemark id="marker-5">\n<styleUrl>#tents</styleUrl>\n<name>ç£ä»”å—ç‡Ÿåœ°(Wan Tsai Peninsula South Campsite)</name>\n<TimeStamp><when>2013-02-22T11:02:2 ...
[10] <Placemark id="marker-6">\n<styleUrl>#tents</styleUrl>\n<name>ç£ä»”è¥¿ç‡Ÿåœ° (Wan Tsai Peninsula West Campsite)</name>\n<TimeStamp><when>2013-02-22T11:02:3 ...
...
```

As you can see there are nodes named as "Placemark", why I can't find the nodes using `xml_find_all`? Did I make any mistakes in my codes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you have a few namespaces.  If you add the prefix to your xpath you can get the nodeset.

```
xml_ns(campsites)
# d1   <-> http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2
# atom <-> http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
# gx   <-> http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2

xml_find_all(campsites, ".//d1:Placemark", xml_ns(campsites))
# {xml_nodeset (45)}
#  [1] <Placemark id="marker-1">\n<styleUrl>#tents</styleUrl>\n<name>流水響營地 ( La ...
#  [2] <Placemark id="marker-2">\n<styleUrl>#tents</styleUrl>\n<name>鶴藪營地(Hok T ...
#  ...
```

To get the text in the cdata, you could use something like

```
xml_text(xml_find_all(campsites, "//d1:description", xml_ns(campsites))) 
# or "//d1:description/text()"
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question, how can I extract the content inside `<![CDATA[<p>...</p>]]>`?